# Assignment fails for result obtained on a custom filter

Tags: python

I create a custom `Filter` inherited from `filter`

```
class Filter(filter):
  def __repr__(self):
    return str(list(self))
  __str__ = __repr__
```

```
x = Filter(lambda y: y%2 == 0, [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

```
x
```

```
[2, 4]
```

but on the second access, the values are no longer there.

```
x
```

```
[]
```

the other way I was able to achieve this is by using function instead of creating a class.

```
def _filter(*args):
    return list(filter(*args))
```

is there a way to make this work using the inheritance way?

Answer (score 0):

(I think) because `filter` returns a generator, calling `__repr__` multiple times returns an empty list after the first call because the generator is exhausted, hence there is nothing to return. You could do something similar you did with your `_filter` function by overwriting the `__new__` magic method and returning a list instead, but I think this is very unintuitive and you would be better of with just `x = list(filter(lambda y: y%2 == 0, [1, 2, 3, 4]))`

```
class Filter(filter):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return list(super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs))

x = Filter(lambda y: y%2 == 0, [1, 2, 3, 4])

print(x)
x.append(5)
print(x)
```